# select from combo box and redraw the chart

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I have this requirement, i have set of graphs, what i need to do is redraw them for the same data list when i select the chart type from a combo box,  but i have no idea how to achieve this, need some help please? any tutorials on this? better..

Comment: How are your existing graphs generated? Show some code, or explain better.

Comment: this is done using codeigniter, i have a view called view_chart.php in that file i have this code                                        $FC = new FusionCharts("Column3D","600","300");                               Column3D is the chart type. i have to show a combo box in this page when i select one of charts from that list this $FC =  new FusionCharts(<chart_type>..); must change the chart type and reload the page?

Comment: this is the source i got this charting functionality http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/169233/

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to create a controller/method that takes the graph ID or name as argument and generates that graph for you on the fly. Then use jQuery to make ajax calls to this controller/method, fetch the generated graph, and replace the existing one on the page.

Example implementation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('select[name=graphList]').change(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var graphID = $(this).val(); //returns the selected option's value

            // make an ajax call to the method/controller to fetch the new graph HTML
            $.ajax({
                // append (new Date()).getTime() to url to prevent session timeout

                url:"http://your_url_here/controller/method/" + graphID + "/" + (new Date()).getTime(),
                    success: function(data){
                            // data should now contain the graph HTML for the new generated graph
                            // simply put this html into the graph div
                            $('#graph').html(data);
                        }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<!-- HTML example below -->
<select name="graphList">
    <option value="1">Graph 1</option>
    <option value="2">Graph 2</option>
    <option value="3">Graph 3</option>
</select>

<div id="graph">

</div>
```

Comment: what is the method i should use in jquery??

Comment: if you have please share some examples please?? links to refer about the implementation??